# C++: reading numerical data until \n

Tags: c++

Is there anyway to obtain numerical data until a new line `\n`?

I know that the `getline()` function works until `\n` is reached, but it is a string function, so I do not know how to make use of it when I need to collect numerical inputs from a file.

I need to be able to do this, because suppose I have numerical data in a file like this:

```
23 42 523 423 53

13 24 242 24 23 23 523 52

42 24 12
```

If I have to collect the sum of each row, then I have to be able to know when a given row ends (when `\n` is reached), this is true if unlike the sample I provided above, there is an unknown number of rows to be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check next character after int to perform your task!

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("File.txt");
    int count = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    char ch = '\0';
    int i = 1;
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        while (ch != '\n')
        {
            in >> temp;
            count = count + temp;
            in.get(ch);
            if (in.eof())
                break;
        }
        cout << "Line : " << i << " Sum : " << count;
        if (!in.eof())
        ch = '\0';
        count = 0;
        i++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Another approach will be to read data in 2D array and sum its every row.

```
int arr[n][m];
int temp=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
in>>arr[i][j];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
{
 temp=temp+arr[i][j];
}
cout<<temp;
temp=0;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, your first example is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Isn't the `if(eof()) break;` part redundant? It should have a `\n` at the end of the file, no? And once it reaches the end of file, the outer loop should not start again.

Comment: No! Then ch always be '\0' and by not getting any input from file we cannot reach eof

Comment: But `in.get(ch)` changes it from `\0` to `\n`, right?